# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jpgt from loader

Tags: unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have builded tess-two using `android-ndk-r12b` in ubuntu, and I have imported it to my project ad module dependency,

When I initializing `TessBaseAPI`, the app crashes and I am getting the following log,

Caused by: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load jpgt` from loader

```
dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/phenomtec.com.tessnative-1.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/phenomtec.com.tessnative-1]: findLibrary returned null
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
    at com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.(TessBaseAPI.java:50)
    at phenomtec.com.tessnative.MainActivity.detectText(MainActivity.java:37) 
    at phenomtec.com.tessnative.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5283) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:150) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
```

[image]